# notepad++ - search and replace for a word and remove line

Tags: search, replace, notepad++

hopefully I can make this understandable:

Just say I have this text in a file:

```
bash-4.2$ 336
1
bash-4.2$ 401
2
bash-4.2$ 403
3
bash-4.2$ 404
4
bash-4.2$ 735
5
bash-4.2$ 894
6
bash-4.2$ 909
7
```

I want to remove everything on the lines that start "bash", so I am looking for this output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

I have been using the regular expression search (with the help of https://regex101.com/r/kT0uE3/1) and if I use this search "bash.*" it removes the line but not the carriage return.

When I change this search to "bash.*\n" it does not find anything (despite regex101 saying it would work).

I think I am missing something obvious and simple but I cannot see the trees for the woods.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There must be a duplicate referring to the mark facility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^bash-.+\R`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  bash-     # literally
  .+        # 1 or more any character but newline
  \R        #any kind of linebreak
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: @weegieavlover: You're welcome, glad it helps. You may consider to upvote, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up